# Communication between docker containers in different networks

Tags: docker, docker-network

If I know a Docker container IP address, I can easily communicate with it from another container, but as long as they are in same network.

My question is, how can I communicate with containers from another network and why can't I access local IP which is on the same machine? I am interested in network explanation why I can access 172.19.0.1 from 172.19.0.2 but I can't access 172.20.0.1 from 172.19.0.2.

What are possible workarounds to making Docker container from one network to communicate with docker container from another network?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a port and then access that port over localhost (or 0.0.0.0 for troubleshooting).

Other than that you could use an alternative to docker network like linking or other things. But I wouldn't suggest that. If you want two containers to communicate with eachother and not the public just create a new network for those two containers.

You can specify that this network is external and they can join it even from different compose files.